# How to add remove certain json arrays from dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, d3.js

I have a sunburst which has following layers of data

world=>continents=>countries=>fuels

NOw I want to include names of elements only until  countries and not names of fuels. With my code I can add names of all elements in the dropdown but not sure how to remove names of fuels from the dropdown.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8wd2xt9n/14/

Full code:

```
var width = 960,
    height = 700,
    radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;
var b = {
    w: 130,
    h: 30,
    s: 3,
    t: 10
};

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, 2 * Math.PI]);

var y = d3.scale.sqrt()
    .range([0, radius]);
var changeArray = [100, 80, 60, 0, -60, -80, -100];
var colorArray = ["#67000d", "#b73e43", "#d5464a", "#f26256", "#fb876e", "#fca78e", "#fcbba1", "#fee0d2", "#fff5f0"];

var svg = d3.select("#diagram").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + (height / 2 + 10) + ")");

var partition = d3.layout.partition()
    .value(function (d) {
    return d.Total;
});

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .startAngle(function (d) {
    return Math.max(0, Math.min(2 * Math.PI, x(d.x)));
})
    .endAngle(function (d) {
    return Math.max(0, Math.min(2 * Math.PI, x(d.x + d.dx)));
})
    .innerRadius(function (d) {
    return Math.max(0, y(d.y));
})
    .outerRadius(function (d) {
    return Math.max(0, y(d.y + d.dy));
});
console.log(arc)

function checkIt(error, root) {
    initializeBreadcrumbTrail();

    //intilaize dropdown
    if (error) throw error;

    var g = svg.selectAll("g")
        .data(partition.nodes(root))
        .enter().append("g");

    var path = g.append("path")
        .attr("d", arc)
        .style("fill", function (d) {
        var color;
        if (d.Total_Change > 100) {
            color = colorArray[0]

        } else if (d.Total_Change > 0 && d.Total_Change < 100) {
            color = colorArray[1]

        } else {
            color = colorArray[2]
        }
        d.color = color;
        return color
    })
        .on("click", click)
        .on("mouseover", mouseover);

    var tooltip = d3.select("body")
        .append("div")
        .attr("id", "tooltips")
        .style("position", "absolute")
        .style("background-color", "#fff")
        .style("z-index", "10")
        .style("visibility", "hidden");
    g.on("mouseover", function (d) {
        return tooltip.style("visibility", "visible")
            .html("<div class=" + "tooltip_container>" + "<h4 class=" + "tooltip_heading>" + d.name.replace(/[_-]/g, " ") + "</h4>" + "<br>" + "<p> Emissions 2013:" + " " + "<br>" + d.Total + " " + "<span>in Million Tons</span></p>" + "<br>" + "<p> Change in Emissions: <span>" + (d.Total_Change / d.Total * 100).toPrecision(3) + "%" + "</span></p>" + "</div>");
    })
        .on("mousemove", function () {
        return tooltip.style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 10) + "px").style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 10) + "px");
    })
        .on("mouseout", function () {
        return tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");
    });

    //creating a dropdown

    var dropDown = d3.select("#dropdown_container")
        .append("select")
        .attr("class", "selection")
        .attr("name", "country-list");

    var nodeArr = partition.nodes(root);
    var options = dropDown.selectAll("option")
        .data(nodeArr)
        .enter()
        .append("option");

    options.text(function (d) {
        var prefix = new Array(d.depth + 1);
        var dropdownValues = d.name.replace(/[_-]/g, " ");
        return dropdownValues;
    }).attr("value", function (d) {
        var dropdownValues = d.name;
        return dropdownValues;
    });



    // transition on click
    function click(d) {
        // fade out all text elements
        console.log(d)
        path.transition()
            .duration(750)
            .attrTween("d", arcTween(d))
            .each("end", function (e, i) {
            // check if the animated element's data e lies within the visible angle span given in d
            if (e.x >= d.x && e.x < (d.x + d.dx)) {
                // get a selection of the associated text element
                var arcText = d3.select(this.parentNode).select("text");
                // fade in the text element and recalculate positions
                arcText.transition().duration(750)
                    .attr("opacity", 1)
                    .attr("transform", function () {
                    return "rotate(" + computeTextRotation(e) + ")"
                })
                    .attr("x", function (d) {
                    return y(d.y);
                });
            }
        });

    };
    d3.select(".selection").on("change", function changePie() {
        var value = this.value;
        var index = this.selectedIndex;
        var dataObj = nodeArr[index];
        path[0].forEach(function (p) {
            var data = d3.select(p).data(); //get the data from the path
            if (data[0].name === value) {
                console.log(data)
                click(data[0]);//call the click function

            }
        });
        console.log(this.value + " :c " + dataObj["Iron and steel"] + " in " + (dataObj.parent && dataObj.parent.name));
    });


};

d3.json("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/heenaI/cbbc5c5f49994f174376/raw/743b3964d1dcc0b005ec2b024414877a36b0bd33/data.json", checkIt);

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", height + "px");

// Interpolate the scales!
function arcTween(d) {
    var xd = d3.interpolate(x.domain(), [d.x, d.x + d.dx]),
        yd = d3.interpolate(y.domain(), [d.y, 1]),
        yr = d3.interpolate(y.range(), [d.y ? 20 : 0, radius]);
    return function (d, i) {
        return i ? function (t) {
            return arc(d);
        } : function (t) {
            x.domain(xd(t));
            y.domain(yd(t)).range(yr(t));
            return arc(d);
        };
    };
}

function initializeBreadcrumbTrail() {
    // Add the svg area.
    var trail = d3.select("#sequence").append("svg:svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", 50)
        .attr("id", "trail");
    // Add the label at the end, for the percentage.
    trail.append("svg:text")
        .attr("id", "endlabel")
        .style("fill", "#000");
}

function breadcrumbPoints(d, i) {
    var points = [];
    points.push("0,0");
    points.push(b.w + ",0");
    points.push(b.w + b.t + "," + (b.h / 2));
    points.push(b.w + "," + b.h);
    points.push("0," + b.h);
    if (i > 0) { // Leftmost breadcrumb; don't include 6th vertex.
        points.push(b.t + "," + (b.h / 2));
    }
    return points.join(" ");
}

// Update the breadcrumb trail to show the current sequence and percentage.
function updateBreadcrumbs(nodeArray) {

    // Data join; key function combines name and depth (= position in sequence).
    var g = d3.select("#trail")
        .selectAll("g")
        .data(nodeArray, function (d) {
        return d.name.replace(/[_-]/g, " ") + d.Total;
    });

    // Add breadcrumb and label for entering nodes.
    var entering = g.enter().append("svg:g");

    entering.append("svg:polygon")
        .attr("points", breadcrumbPoints)
        .style("fill", "#d3d3d3");

    entering.append("svg:text")
        .attr("x", (b.w + b.t) / 2)
        .attr("y", b.h / 2)
        .attr("dy", "0.35em")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text(function (d) {
        return d.name.replace(/[_-]/g, " ");
    });

    // Set position for entering and updating nodes.
    g.attr("transform", function (d, i) {
        return "translate(" + i * (b.w + b.s) + ", 0)";
    });

    // Remove exiting nodes.
    g.exit().remove();

    // Now move and update the percentage at the end.
    d3.select("#trail").select("#endlabel")
        .attr("x", (nodeArray.length + 0.5) * (b.w + b.s))
        .attr("y", b.h / 2)
        .attr("dy", "0.35em")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle");

    // Make the breadcrumb trail visible, if it's hidden.
    d3.select("#trail")
        .style("visibility", "");
}

function getAncestors(node) {
    var path = [];
    var current = node;
    while (current.parent) {
        path.unshift(current);
        current = current.parent;
    }
    return path;
}

function mouseover(d) {

    var sequenceArray = getAncestors(d);
    updateBreadcrumbs(sequenceArray);
}
```

Code that creates dropdown

/creating a dropdown

```
var dropDown = d3.select("#dropdown_container")
    .append("select")
    .attr("class", "selection")
    .attr("name", "country-list");

var nodeArr = partition.nodes(root);
var options = dropDown.selectAll("option")
    .data(nodeArr)
    .enter()
    .append("option");

options.text(function (d) {
    var prefix = new Array(d.depth + 1);
    var dropdownValues = d.name.replace(/[_-]/g, " ");
    return dropdownValues;
}).attr("value", function (d) {
    var dropdownValues = d.name;
    return dropdownValues;
});
```

[Data structure can be viewed here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/heenaI/cbbc5c5f49994f174376/raw/743b3964d1dcc0b005ec2b024414877a36b0bd33/data.json)

Comment: Post only relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are grabbing the values of the dropdown menu from the nodes of the partition, you have the depth of the nodes at hand when setting up the dropdown, thus you can filter:

```
    var nodeArr = partition.nodes(root);
    var options = dropDown.selectAll("option")
      .data(nodeArr.filter(function(d){return d.depth < 3;}))
      .enter()
      .append("option");
```

I hope that helps!

(see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8wd2xt9n/15/))

Answer (score 0):

I would just pre-process the data.  In the original root structure you know the countries are 2 levels down so:

```
var countries = [];
root.children.forEach(function (c){
    c.children.forEach(function (d){
        countries.push(d.name.replace(/[_-]/g, " "));
    });
});
```

And the dropdown becomes:

```
var options = dropDown.selectAll("option")
    .data(countries)
    .enter()
    .append("option");

options.text(function (d) {
    return d;
}).attr("value", function (d) {
    return d;
});
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8wd2xt9n/16/).